# How to move desktop icons using qdbus in a bash script (plasma)

Tags: bash, kde, plasma, qdbus

How to move desktop icons using qdbus in a bash script

I am using KDE plasma in folder view mode

Comment: have you tried taking a look at: `qdbusviewer` it is a UI for `gdbus` maybe there you can find a solution to your problem that you then can transfer to a bash script solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need. Move what icons? All? Specific ones? To where? Just change their placement on your desckop or move to another folder? If the first, change to where? If the second, to what folder? What do you have so far?